# JPA forming query which fails at program running

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa

I am doing the following query in JPA:

```
@NamedQuery(name = PlayerSkill.DELETE_ALL_BOT_DATA,
                query = "DELETE FROM PlayerSkill s WHERE s.player.id " +
                        "IN (SELECT p.id FROM Player p WHERE p.team.id " +
                        "IN (SELECT t.id FROM Manager m JOIN m.teamInfo t WHERE m.localUserId IS NULL))")
```

And receiving the following exception when calling appropriate DAO function, which is calling the JPA named query using executeUpdate:

```
7818 [Thread-12] WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
7818 [Thread-12] ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near "cross"
  Position: 30
7828 [Thread-12] ERROR c.m.s.threads.ServerInitializer - null
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387) ~[AbstractEntityManagerImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) ~[AbstractEntityManagerImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1397) ~[AbstractEntityManagerImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:111) ~[AbstractQueryImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at com.magnifi.pennantrace.dao.player.PlayerSkillDAO.deleteBotTeamsData(PlayerSkillDAO.java:25) ~[PlayerSkillDAO.class:na]
    at com.magnifi.schedserv.seasonstartend.SeasonGeneration.deleteAllBotRelatedData(SeasonGeneration.java:1457) ~[SeasonGeneration.class:na]
    at com.magnifi.schedserv.seasonstartend.SeasonGeneration.generateSeason(SeasonGeneration.java:109) ~[SeasonGeneration.class:na]
    at com.magnifi.schedserv.threads.ServerInitializer.generateEndStart(ServerInitializer.java:161) [ServerInitializer.class:na]
    at com.magnifi.schedserv.threads.ServerInitializer.initSystem(ServerInitializer.java:80) [ServerInitializer.class:na]
    at com.magnifi.schedserv.threads.SchedulerThread.run(SchedulerThread.java:38) [SchedulerThread.class:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123) ~[SQLStateConversionDelegate.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) ~[StandardSQLExceptionConverter.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) ~[SqlExceptionHelper.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) ~[SqlExceptionHelper.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189) ~[ResultSetReturnImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.doExecute(BasicExecutor.java:108) ~[BasicExecutor.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.BasicExecutor.execute(BasicExecutor.java:77) ~[BasicExecutor.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.execute(DeleteExecutor.java:124) ~[DeleteExecutor.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.executeUpdate(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:415) ~[QueryTranslatorImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(HQLQueryPlan.java:282) ~[HQLQueryPlan.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1215) ~[SessionImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:116) ~[QueryImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:198) ~[QueryImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:102) ~[AbstractQueryImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "cross"
  Position: 30
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:417) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:363) ~[postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:100) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:100) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:8.0.3]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186) ~[ResultSetReturnImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
7832 [Thread-12] ERROR c.m.s.threads.SchedulerThread - null
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:72) ~[TransactionImpl.class:4.2.8.Final]
    at com.magnifi.schedserv.threads.SchedulerThread.run(SchedulerThread.java:39) ~[SchedulerThread.class:na]
```

The real sql query on that exception is:

```
delete from bb_player_skills cross join bb_players player1_ where id in (select player2_.id from bb_players player2_ where player2_.team_id in (select teaminfo4_.id from bb_manager manager3_ inner join bb_team_info teaminfo4_ on manager3_.bb_team_info_id=teaminfo4_.id where manager3_.local_user_id is null))
```

I can't understand why its forming the query using "cross" as it says in the error log. 
For a different table the same query works well:

```
@NamedQuery(name=PlayerStat.DELETE_BOT_DATA,
        query = "DELETE FROM PlayerStat s WHERE s.player.id " +
                "IN (SELECT p.id FROM Player p WHERE p.team.id " +
                "IN (SELECT t.id FROM Manager m JOIN m.teamInfo t WHERE m.localUserId IS NULL))")
```

And real sql formed by this query is not containing "cross":

```
delete from bb_player_stat where bb_players_id in (select player1_.id from bb_players player1_ where player1_.team_id in (select teaminfo3_.id from bb_manager manager2_ inner join bb_team_info teaminfo3_ on manager2_.bb_team_info_id=teaminfo3_.id where manager2_.local_user_id is null))
```

The relation of tables is same also: player skill is one to one to players , same as player stat

**EDIT:**
for player skills (the one where cross is used) the entity:

```
@JSON(include=false)
private Player player;

@Id
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="bb_players_id", nullable=false)
public Player getPlayer() {
    return this.player;
}
```

And for PlayerStat:

```
private Player player;
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="bb_players_id", nullable=false)
public Player getPlayer() {
    return this.player;
}
```

In the Player entity:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="player", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public PlayerSkill getPlayerSkill() {
        return this.playerSkill;
    }

@OneToOne(mappedBy="player", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public PlayerStat getPlayerStats() {
        return this.playerStats;
    }
```

Comment: Condition WHERE someID IN (select anotherID from...) can be replaced with JOIN (select anotherID from...) sub ON sub.anotherID=someID

Comment: The `cross join` (normally) will be used, if you have to join tables by primary key. It seems to me that you use a `@PrimaryKeyJoin` in your first case and `@JoinColumn` or `mappedby` in your second case

Comment: @drkunibar please see edit to the question.

Comment: @naxinus Maybe it is a problem with the `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`. Can you try to add `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` on `getPlayerSkills`

Comment: @drkunibar I tried removing fetch=FetchType.LAZY, same problem.

Comment: I've tried adding @Fetch as you have suggested, same problem. no change.